# Сортировка и фильтрация Yii2 GridView

Tags: yii2, gridview

Код:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'tableOptions' => [
                            'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'
                        ],
                        'columns' => [
                            'id',
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'name',
                                'label'=>'Заголовок',
                                'content'=>function($data){
                                    return \common\models\Helper::titleFormat($data['id']);
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'username',
                                'label'=>'Пользователь',
                                'content'=>function($data){
                                    return \frontend\models\Items::getPropLabel($data['id'], '_username_');
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'phone',
                                'label'=>'Телефон',
                                'content'=>function($data){
                                    return \frontend\models\Items::getPropLabel($data['id'], '_phone_');
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'status',
                                'label'=>'Состояние',
                                'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\ItemStatus::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
                                'content'=>function($data){
                                    return \backend\models\ItemStatus::findOne($data['status'])['name'];
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'label',
                                'label'=>'Метка',
                                'content'=>function($data){
                                    $l = \backend\models\Labels::findOne($data['label']);
                                    return '<span class="label '.$l['class'].'">'.$l['name'].'</span>';
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                                'template' => '{update} {delete}',
                                'buttons' => [
                                    'update' => function ($url,$model,$key) {
                                        return '<a class="btn btn-info" onclick="item.edit(
'.$key.');"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';
                                    },
                                    'delete' => function ($url,$model,$key) {
                                        return '<button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="delete" data-id="'.$key.'" data-table="items"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
                                    },
                                ],
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]); ?>
```

По полям `id`, `status` и `label` автоматически добавилась сортировка, а по остальным нет.

Как заставить появится сортировке для остальных полей? И как добавить фильтрацию по каждому выводимому столбцу?

Если у вас есть ссылка на подробную документацию, буду благодарен, потому, что то что нахожу в гугле, ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я бы посмотрел SearchModel, вполне возможно, что эти поля виртуальные. Надо детально глянуть.

Comment: да, их в самой модели нету. если нету - сортировку не возможно сделать?

Comment: Всё возможно, у Вас searchModel есть? генерировали её в gii? Если да, то выложите её сюда, и ещё выложите саму модель по которой ищет dataProvider